# Should I use several connections if I use threads to fetch lots of data?

Tags: c#, multithreading, db2, ibm-midrange

I'm using the iDB2/iSeries connector for AS400 to fetch at once a lot of data. I'm creating one connection to the database and, in order to increase performances, I use this one with several threads (something like 10). In all, 50 commands are created and then disposed, and every DataReader is closed.

All is working great except one thing: I don't manage to close that connection. I got the following exception (the first line means 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object'):

```
    {"La référence d'objet n'est pas définie à une instance d'un objet."}
    [System.NullReferenceException]: {"La référence d'objet n'est pas définie à une instance d'un objet."}
    Data: {System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal}
    HelpLink: null
    HResult: -2147467261
    InnerException: null
    Message: "La référence d'objet n'est pas définie à une instance d'un objet."
    Source: "IBM.Data.DB2.iSeries"
    StackTrace: "   à IBM.Data.DB2.iSeries.iDB2Connection.Close()\r\n   à WcfApp.Metier.InitApp() dans c:\\projet\\WSApp.cs:ligne 450"
    TargetSite: {Void Close()}
```

Comment: Does the exception still occur if you use `using` around the connection, rather than explicitly calling `Close()`? Frankly, I can't remember the last time I ever called `Close()` - `using` tends to be much more convenient *and* reliable.

Comment: I've used 'using', but does the connection.dispose() method really close the connection ? I don't think so: if I do it manually, I can see that the status of the connection is still 'open'.

Comment: neither `Close` *nor* `Dispose` really close the connection - or, depending on the configuration, **both do**. By default, most providers use a connection pool, so both `Close` and `Dispose` merely put the *underlying* connection back into the available pool. It would be a misunderstanding to think that `Dispose` is doing something wrong or different here. If connection-pooling is disabled (on the connection string, usually), then both `Close` and `Dispose` will terminate the underlying connection.

Comment: Clear and concise: thank you.

Comment: It is usually unwise to share a single connection between multiple threads.

Answer (score 2):

1. Using [Task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead of Thread will make your data processing more transparent and clear.
2. Care about sharing your connection - use the [lock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz.aspx) statement, if needed.
3. Read about transaction scopes and connections pooling - that is what you need to know when using DB connections.

Comment: I've replaces all the threads by tasks: not sure if it will change anything but the code is much more clear! Thanks. I'm reading on your advice: I'll be back soon ;). A little question: do I really need locks if I don't update/insert/delete ?

Comment: @Nicolas if you are accessing the same connection from multiple threads, then yes: absolutely. Connections are not usually intended for concurrent access, so the `lock` here simply synchronizes access to the connection itself. If you are *not* using the same connection from multiple threads, then: no.